# Disable Kendo Telerik UI font icon on condition

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I've tried to disable the web font icon on condition in the Kendo grid but I don't know how to do this!
This is my code snippet but it doesn't work. 
I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

```
command: [
          {
              name: "Revocation",
              click: revocation,
              template: "<div><a href='\\#' class='k-grid-Revocation'><i class='k-icon k-i-close'></i></a></div>"
           },
          ],width: 30
```

```
 dataBound: function (e) {
                    var grid = $("#grid_Shipment").data("kendoGrid");
                    var items = e.sender.items();
                    $.each(items, function (index) {
                        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
                        $("tr[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "']").find(".k-grid .k-icon").each(function (index) {
                            if (dataItem.ShipmentStatus != 1) {
                                $(this).addClass('k-state-disabled').prop('disabled', true);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't working, but note that the template can be a function which gets the dataItem as a parameter, so that would make your code much simpler. Try that approach.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with columns custom command is that you can't access dataItem of row and you can't manipulate them like in column template. Official documentation, or better say, official forum support says approach it same way as you use it (with dataBound). I find it a bit too complex for small functionality as disable icon or something like that.

I came up with workaround, its not clean but im ok with it. There is `visible` function that is executed on initialization of the row, there you can access row dom and manipulate with it. For example i added class `custom-disabled` with item data condition:

```
command: [
    {
        name: 'delete',
        template: '<a class="btn btn-action btn-lg k-grid-delete" href="\\#"><span class="fas fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>',
        click(e) {
            _deleteCommand(_getGridData(e));
        },
        visible: function (item) {
            if (item.disableDelete) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("[data-uid=" + item.uid + "]").find('.k-grid-delete').addClass('custom-disabled');
                }, 0);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
]
//CSS
.custom-disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: .65;
}
```

Or if you are ok with it you can hide that command like this:

```
command: [
    {
        name: 'delete',
        template: '<a class="btn btn-action btn-lg k-grid-delete" href="\\#"><span class="fas fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>',
        visible: function (item) {
            return item.disableDelete;
        }
    }
]
```